# How to check the client locale date-time is correct before taking it for processing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want the current locale datetime for my application . But before taking the date , I need to confirm the local date and time are correct . -I mean , if the  user changed the date and time with a  wrong date in their machine , I need to raise an error or notification to correct the date time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- if the data-time of your server is correct, you can return it to client  through putting it in a hidden tag with specific id. now, in client side you can read and compare it with local date. suppose that our hidden element is:

```
<input type='hidden' value='2019/01/05 08:17Z' id='server_time'/>
```

now we can compare it with the local date-time (put this code in `window.onload=function(){/*.. here ..*/}`):

```
//if the elapsed time relative to the server time is greater than 60 seconds ...
if((new Date() - new Date(document.getElementById("server_time").value))/1000 > 60) alert("Please correct your system date!!"); //or any thing
```

2- if you don't have access to server side..

in this case, you can try at list this two ways:

a- you can use a free `api` for getting the correct time. please look at this sample:

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now");
hr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(hr.readyState!=4) return;
    if(hr.status != 200 && hr.status != 304) return alert("err");
    if((new Date() - new Date(JSON.parse(hr.responseText).currentDateTime))/1000 > 60) alert("Please correct your system date!!");
}
hr.send();
```

b- another way is:

(if the time of your server is correct,) you can fetch the date from `header info`! for this, you can call a simple action from your host (that point to a blank page or even a page that is not exists!). now try like this:

```
var hr=new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", "blankpage.html");
hr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(hr.readyState!=4) return;
    if((new Date() - new Date(hr.getAllResponseHeaders().match(/date *\: *(.+)[\r\n]/i)[1]))/1000>50) alert("Please correct your system date!!");
};
hr.send();
```